# Having Issue On WordPress Metabox Gallery and Attachment URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Using WordPress 4.5.2 , I am trying to add Gallery Metabox to post using [this solution](https://github.com/zulfnore/gallery-metabox) but in js part I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

on

```
attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url
```

not sure this is JavaScript or WP issue but can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

js:

```
file_frame.on('select', function() {
      var listIndex = $('#gallery-metabox-list li').index($('#gallery-metabox-list li:last')),
          selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');

      selection.map(function(attachment, i) {
        attachment = attachment.toJSON(),
        index      = listIndex + (i + 1);
var thumb = attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url;
 alert(thumb);
        $('#gallery-metabox-list').append('<li><input type="hidden" name="vdw_gallery_id[' + index + ']" value="' + attachment.id + '"><img class="image-preview" src="' + attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url + '"><a class="change-image button button-small" href="#" data-uploader-title="Change image" data-uploader-button-text="Change image">Change image</a><br><small><a class="remove-image" href="#">Remove image</a></small></li>');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple and it worker for me.

The error says that there are no images cropped as thumbnails.

Go go Settings -> Media in your WP admin panel and set the thumbnail size.

Than you have to regenerate the images that were already uploaded before with Force Regenerate Thumbnails plugin or just upload new images.